# How do I easily type a £ symbol

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

On US international keyboard I was able to type the £ symbol Ralt4. Now I get ¤. Is there any easy way to type a £ symbol in the document.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean other than holding Alt, and typing 0163 on the numpad, and then releasing Alt?  That is likely the most commonly supported method on a typical US keyboard.  (Just tested, even within this web browser visiting SuperUser, on Win7.)

Comment: I just typed  alt0163 and released the alt. using US international Key board which I mentioned in my question